# One Specific Facebook Status on Website

Tags: facebook

I would like to build a website where user can post on of their Facebook status messages by submitting the URL of the status.

(The URL can be retrieved by right-clicking on the " ago" under the status message and copying the link.)

- After changing the privacy to public and submitting the link, it
  should be displayed on my website, with the possibility to like,
  share and comment the status.
- Is there a way to do that? I thought about iFrames but is there a
  more beautiful solution? :)

To make it more clear: I do not want all status updates from a user, just a specific one - Therefore I want to use the URL which leads directly to the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have :

> right-clicking on the " ago" under the status message and copying the
>   link

In your application's flow, then you could parse the URL that is there to extract information about the post/album/photo/status/etc... 
*Remember that a user could click on anyone of those types of posts*

The URL would look something like this : 
https://www.facebook.com/rozen.lior/posts/10150498318655888

From that URL you can extract the ID of the post - 10150498318655888 and query it through the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) like this :
https://graph.facebook.com/10150498318655888...

If you only want "status updates" then you will have to make sure that the link that the user has given is indeed a "post"... For example a URL taken from the same place of a photo album would look like this :

`https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.XXX.YYY.ZZZ&type=1`
There are 3 groups of numbers here (XXX,YYY,ZZZ) - the first batch of numbers is the same as the post ID - only it will give you details of the photo album instead.

You can experiment by using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: Thank you Lix! I played around with the Graph API Explorer and wrote a little PHP script which takes the URL, finds the unique ID of the posts, asks graph.facebook.com for information like the name of the creator, the actual message of the post and the number of likes.
Unfortunatley this is only working with posts from Facebook "Sites", not from user-profiles even if the post is made public :( I need to figure out how this could work without getting the permission of the user...this will be tricky, I guess. Any ideas?

Comment: You are very welcome @user1052424! However : ..."without getting the permission of the user." - no... not without the correct permissions.  The permission you are looking for is `read_stream`.  See the [Permissions Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Hmm, okay thank you. I was hoping for a better answer, however I was expecting something like that :D Next step is to figure out, how a logged-in Facebook user can like someone else's posted status on my website

Comment: If someone else is reading this: A "Like" can be done with a POST request similar to this https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes